# How to mole the GetEnumerator method for SPJobDefinitionCollection

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sharepoint, moles, pex

**Can somebody help me please?**

I need create a unit test using moles for this method:

```
   public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        SPWebApplication webApp = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;
        foreach (SPJobDefinition job in webApp.JobDefinitions)
            if (job.Name == "AAAA") job.Delete();
        AssistantJob aJob = new AssistantJob(webApp);
        SPDailySchedule schedule = new SPDailySchedule();
        schedule.BeginHour = 2;
        schedule.BeginMinute = 30;
        schedule.BeginSecond = 0;
        schedule.EndHour = 3;
        schedule.EndMinute = 30;
        schedule.EndSecond = 0;
        aJob.Schedule = schedule;
        aJob.Update();
    }
```

**But, when I execute the test the following error message appears:**

```
failing test: MoleNotImplementedException, SPPersistedObjectCollection`1.GetEnumerator() was not moled.
```

**This error occur in this line:**

```
        foreach (SPJobDefinition job in webApp.JobDefinitions)
```

**This is my unit test code:**

```
    [PexMethod]
    public void FeatureActivated(
        [PexAssumeUnderTest]ApprovalAssistantCleanupEventReceiver target
    )
    {
        MSPFarm.BehaveAsNotImplemented();

        BSPFeatureReceiverProperties props = new BSPFeatureReceiverProperties();
        BSPFeature feature = new BSPFeature();
        MSPWebApplication webapp = new MSPWebApplication();

        props.Feature = feature;
        feature.Parent = webapp.Instance;
        webapp.JobDefinitionsGet = () => new MSPJobDefinitionCollection();

        target.FeatureActivated(props);

    }
```

I've read on the internet I need use Binding to implement GetEnumerator() into a collection. Then changed my unit test to implement this, but the error is the same.
The AssistantJob class implement the JobDefinition abstract class.

```
        webapp.JobDefinitionsGet = () => new MSPJobDefinitionCollection().Bind(new MApprovalAssistantJob[] {
            new MAssistantJob() {  },
            new MAssistantJob() {  }
        });
```

Can someone help me to add **MAssistantJob** items inside the **MSPJobDefinitionCollection**???

I'm sorry my English isn't good.

Thanks very much.